# VM Server and Windows Home Server 2008

Tags: hard-drive, vmware-server, windows-home-server, scsi

I'm having issues setting up VM Server with Windows Home Server 2008

Right on setup it is giving a popup that says

"Hard Drive capable of hosting Windows Home Server was not found. Would
you like to load additional storage drivers."

I believe it is because the hard drive is set to SCSI, but don't have an option to set it as IDE, anyone able to get this working before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing to a SCSI virtual drive should work fine...  There's a good guide available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/virtualization-coach/?p=104), and should work even though it's referring to VMWare Workstation instead of Server.

Comment: Thanks that worked.. had to download the SCSI drivers from http://downloads.vmware.com/d/details/scsi_dt_server_wkst_ace/dCpiQGh3YmRAZQ== and change the SCSI controller type to Bus Logic.. last part was important, did not work if controller wasn't bus logic